# Python package for plotting in Arctic Stereographic CRS

Tags: python, mapping, matplotlib-basemap, folium, cartopy

I am plotting the drift track of multiple buoys in the arctic. I need a map in the polar stereographic projection and then to plot many latitude/longitude pairs from a dataframe on the the map. What packages work with this. I thought that Folium looked really nice, but I don't think that it can do different projections. There is also basemap, cartopy...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Cartopy supports a [north polar stereographic projection](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/crs/projections.html#northpolarstereo) and can be used with matplotlib to create a map and plot datapoints. The [Cartopy documentation](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/intro.html) includes examples of how to plot points on a map projection.

Answer (score 0):

[GeoViews](https://geoviews.org/index.html) supports [NorthPolarStereo projection](https://geoviews.org/user_guide/Projections.html). GeoViews using a Bokeh extension support map interactivity like panning and zoom similar to Folium.